# How to load selected rows from sql database to DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview, visual-studio-2017

I need to display selected data into my DataGridView which according to selected PO_No from the combo box.SO i tried this.But displayed only a single row for selected PO_No

```
public void loadPOCarttable()
    {
        DynamicConnection con = new DynamicConnection();

        try
        {
            con.sqlquery("select b.BookName,b.ISBN_No,p.OrderQuantity,p.UnitPrice,p.Total from TBL_Book b, TBL_PO_Cart p where b.ISBN_No=p.ISBN_No and PO_No='" + cmbPO.Text + "'");
            con.mysqlconnection();
            con.datatable();
            con.dataread();
            //con.table.Load(con.datareader);
            int i = 0;
            while (con.datareader.Read())
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = con.datareader["BookName"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = con.datareader["ISBN_No"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = con.datareader["OrderQuantity"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = con.datareader["UnitPrice"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = con.datareader["Total"].ToString();
                i++;
            }
            //this.dataGridView1.DataSource = con.table;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

and display this error.How can i solve this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSaSu.png)

Comment: You need to ensure that row and cell exists.

Comment: You could just set the grid's datasource to the DataTable and be done with it. That would handle creating all the rows and cells for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have all the cells need, then try it like this:

```
while (con.datareader.Read())
{
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
    row.Cells[0].Value = con.datareader["BookName"].ToString();
    row.Cells[1].Value = con.datareader["ISBN_No"].ToString();
    row.Cells[2].Value = con.datareader["OrderQuantity"].ToString();
    row.Cells[3].Value = con.datareader["UnitPrice"].ToString();
    row.Cells[4].Value = con.datareader["Total"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

**Update**

Use `this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` to clear previous data.

Comment: I tried this.But if i select another PO_No that data also load to this DataGridView without clear previous data. So how can i solve this problem too.please.thank for your answer

Comment: where should i put this " this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();"

Comment: Before your while loop

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it helps. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.